# Fade animation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

How can I make a fade animation from one View controller to the next. So basically what I want is when I click a button, it fades from the current view controller to the one it's linked to. Is there a way to do this. I've been searching for a while and haven't been able to find anything in Swift. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you navigating the viewcontroller using push or as modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer. Instead of making every scene a different ViewController, I just made every scene an SKScene and used one ViewController for the entire project. Now, to get from one scene to another I used this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        // Get the location of the touch in this scene
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        // Check if the location of the touch is within the button's bound

        if L1.contains(location) {
            let gameScene = GameScene()
            gameScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
            gameScene.view?.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
            self.scene?.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
            print("tapped!")
        }
}
```

This allowed me to use the line "self.scene?.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition" to achieve this transition. The reason I transferred over from view controllers was not only for the animations but also to make the app more efficient and to have it work better and be smoother.

Answer (score 5):

```
let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.4
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade
    self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcID") as! My_ViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

Comment: Would I put this in a button press function inside of the view controller that has the button or would I put this in a storyboard segue class?

Comment: Put it on button press function.

Comment: It's almost working however I keep getting this error on the line that says "self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)" : Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1004d2588)

Comment: self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, but I'll keep working on it. If I figure out a solution I'll post it.

Comment: Okay great. keep finding.